# startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame and isDeviceMotionActive

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am trying to use `startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame` of `CMMotionManager`, but I found a strange bug (?), that `isDeviceMotionActive = false` after this call. However, it returns correct `true` after `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue`.

Building for iOS 8.4.

Any hints why this property is not supported for `startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame`?

Comment: It probably is false because device motion is not yet active. I would guess that if you check it after a second or two it will return true. Device motion uses hardware features that take time to turn on. I don't know why it would immediately return true after you call startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue. That seems stranger to me than the other way around.

Comment: For me it is more logical to return true immediately after request as it indicates that updates were requested. Because either way you are in a situation when you are not aware of a system state (as request can't fail).

Comment: But you are correct, it returns `true` after some time.